# Adding the article in joomla below the existing article by admin privelage

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

Have problem in adding new article in joomla the articles are getting added at the top instead of the bottom of existing article.

Comment: Have you tried changing the order or them?

Comment: Joomla has about 8 options for display order in the front end and a lot of ways to sort in the back end. Do sort by create date reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sorting order of Joomla articles can be set in several different places, ranging from default settings to menu-specific settings, each one taking precedence over the previous setting.

The best way to make sure you have control over the way your articles are sorted is in your menu item editor. You should check several settings in the "Layout" tab (or "Blog Layout" if that's what you're using):

1. **Category Order** - I recommend using "No order", or else the articles will be sorted by category first.
2. **Article Order** - Use "Oldest first".
3. **Date for Ordering** - Created/modified/published. You probably want to use "Published" here. If you set this to "Modified", any article will be placed last when you save it.